# Not able to access zeppelin 8080/8180 outside VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache-zeppelin, cloudera-quickstart-vm

This question might have answered but I am not able to solve. Need some help.

Issues: Not able to see http://127.0.0.1:8080/ outside VM but able to see http://127.0.0.1:8088/ and other ports.

I am using zeppelin-0.8.2 in Oracle VM.Cloudera Quickstart is used for Spark.I am able to see the port http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/ inside VM and could create notebook.
VM Config Network :  NAT+Host Only

I have also tried to change the port from 8080 to 8180 still same issues. I am missing some thing. Please let me know.
[Port 8088](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp7BW.png)

[image: VM Network]

Comment: It's possible Zeppelin is only configured to bind on localhost, and not externally. Can you show the Zeppelin config file?

Comment: zeppline-site.xml  >>>>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.addr</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1</value>
  <description>Server binding address</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.port</name>
  <value>8180</value>
 </property>
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.ssl.port</name>
  <value>8443</value>
  <description>Server ssl port. (used when ssl proper</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.context.path</name>
  <value>/</value>
  <description>Context Path of the Web Application</description>
</property>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose Zeppelin externally, you must update the configs

```
<name>zeppelin.server.addr</name>
<value>0.0.0.0</value>
```